# Find last header element using jquery

Tags: jquery

how can I find Header 3 using :header
note: it could be either h1 or h2 or h3 as these tags are created dynamically, need to use header.

```
 <h1>Header 1</h1>
 <p>Contents 1</p>
 <h1>Header 2</h1>
 <p>Contents 2</p>
 <h1>Header 3</h1>
 <p>Contents 2</p>


 $( ":header" ).css({ background: "#ccc", color: "blue" });
```

Comment: what if not sure if it is h1 or h2 or h3 etc..

Comment: Yes your are right `:header` has to be there.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(":header:last").css({ background: "#ccc", color: "blue" });
```

This will select you the last `:header` tag that exists in entire page, and apply your css to it.

You can do it through CSS by suffixing `:last` any selector (in this case `:header`). Or you can do it through jQuery by using the built in function `.last()`

```
$(":header").last().css({ background: "#ccc", color: "blue" });
```

Comment: OP updated question, "note: it could be either h1 or h2 or h3 as these tags are created dynamically, need to use header."

Answer (score 2):

Use `.last()`

```
 $( ":header" ).last().css({ background: "#ccc", color: "blue" });
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4vw2/)

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r7ZyL/)

Use **[`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)** Selector.

```
$(':header:last').css({ background: "#ccc", color: "blue" });
```

Alternative : `.last()`

```
$(':header').last().css({ background: "#ccc", color: "blue" });
```

Comment: @afaolek `:header` is a jQuery pseudo selector. Check the Demo!